# Not able to invoke second AWS lambda function from first AWS lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm not able to invoke second lambda function from first one, I'm not getting any error message but page is keep on loading and its timing out after 5 mins. What could be the reason, I'm not getting where I'm doing mistake. Can someone help me to resolve this issue:

First Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="triggerEmail",InvocationType='Event')
```

Second Lambda Function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return 'Hello from triggerEmail'
```

If I execute, page is keep on loading and not printing any log as well.
Attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: Have you worked out the issue?  I am not sure the rest of the code in the first function but you do need a return in it. Also have you setup a iam role to give permission for the first function to call the second function.  Let me know I will post the code that I used to get your sample to work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you placed the first Lambda function inside a VPC. If so, it won't have access to the AWS API (or anything else that exists outside the VPC) and will timeout when trying to connect to those resources. You would either need to remove the function from the VPC, or add a NAT gateway to your VPC